# react-data-grid | how to use multiple header renderer

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

We are upgrading from version 5 to 7.0.0-canary.48 of [react-data-grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/README.md). In version 5, we have both header filters and column reordering features. Not sure how can we implement both with the latest version.

I found a couple of examples of header renderers but could not find any way to use multiple renderers for both column ordering and filtering.

[HeaderFilters](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/website/demos/HeaderFilters.tsx)
[ColumnsReordering](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/main/website/demos/ColumnsReordering.tsx)